# Waiting for an answer from server on http request in Angular 2

Tags: http, angular, get

I have a little problem with my Angular2 app. I want to get some data from server for my user login, but my code is going ahead and I have a lot of bugs with it. I want to wait for answer from server, then do something with my data.

This is my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { User } from './user';

@Injectable()

export class UserService {

    public usersTmp: Array<Object> = new Array<Object>();
    public users: Array<User>;
    public user: User = new User();
    public noteToSend;
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getUsers() {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Accept', 'q=0.8;application/json;q=0.9');

        this.http.get('/AngularApp/api/users', { headers: headers })
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log(data);
                this.usersTmp = data;
            },
            err => console.error(err),
            () => console.log('done')
            );

        this.users = new Array<User>();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.usersTmp.length; i++) {
            this.user = new User();
            this.user.id = this.usersTmp[i]["userId"];
            this.user.name = this.usersTmp[i]["userName"];
            this.user.email = this.usersTmp[i]["userEmail"];
            this.user.pass = this.usersTmp[i]["userPassword"];

            this.users.push(this.user);

        }
        return this.users;
    }
```

As I noticed my code is going to the for loop until I get answer from server, so I return just empty array. Anyone can help me with that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the service, you should return the `Observable` that your component can subscribe to. It cannot work they way you do it due to the asynchronous mode of the `get` request.

As a proposal, your service could look similar to this

```
getUsers() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'q=0.8;application/json;q=0.9');

    return this.http.get('/AngularApp/api/users', { headers: headers })
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

And the relevant part of your component like this:

```
 constructor(private userService:UserService) {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
      data => this.iterateOverUsers(data));
 }

 iterateOverUsers(data) {
   // here comes your for loop
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now everything looks fine ;)